# graph that have edge that connect remainder

Tags: discrete-mathematics, graph-theory

for integer m,  $S \subseteq \{1,2,3...m-1\}$ and undirected graph $G_{m,s} =(V_m, E_{m,s})$ with definition below

$V_{m} ={1,2,...m}$

$E_{m,S}=\{{u,v}|((u-v) mod m) \in S\}$

I need to find equation of diameter  of $G_{m,\{1,2,..k\}}$ where $k \leq \frac{m}{2}$  using m and k

From the problem I know that there is edge in graph if $u,v$ have same remainder modulo n, which mean is u-v is multiple of n ,

for example $G_{6,\{2\}}$
means vertices is {1,2...6} and edges $(u-v) $ mod 2 $\in S$
so  we can partition $ 1 \equiv 3 \equiv 5 $ mod 2  and $ 2 \equiv 4 \equiv 6$ mod 2

Edges = $\{\{1,3\},\{3,1\}\{4,2\},\{2.4\},\{3,5\},\{5,3\},\{6,4\},\{4,6\},\{6,2\}\{2,6\},\{1,5\},\{5,1\}\}$

but how can i conclude and proof diameter of graph?

what i think is that $G_{m,\{1,2,..k\}}$ and $k \leq \frac{m}{2}$ have edge in every connected vertex so radius and diameter is 1, because if i draw the graph there is edge connected all vertices

Comment: I confuse some notations. Are $V_m = \{1,2,\ldots,m\}$ and $E_{m,S} = \{ \{u,v\} | [(u-v \mod m)] \in S\}$?
You said that $G_{m,S}$ is undirected, but your definition of the edge set depending on ordering of $u,v$. Do we need to change to $E_{m,S} = \{ \{u,v\} | [(|u-v| \mod m)] \in S\}$ or $E_{m,S} = \{ \{u,v\} | [(u-v \mod m)] \in S \textrm{ or } (v-u \mod m) \in S\}$?

Comment: @Dong-gyuKim $E_{m,S}=\{{u,v}|((u-v) mod$ $ m) \in S\}$ there is edge between (u,v) and (v,u) since it is undirected. S is set of remainder mod n

Comment: @Dong-gyuKim I edited the Edges in my post